# Beginner Questions about Android 3D

Tags: android, graphics, open-source, opengl-es

I am doing an academic project, which involves learning android and i needed to know the following details about android OS capabilities along with any **good free and open-source 3D rendering API**

1. Can i display a sphere,cone, a sphere (divided into different positions) ... i want it more like a 3D Graph
2. Can i display a 3D Terrain Map
3. Can i move the camera 360 degrees, i.e i want to be able to see my models from all angles from just the swipe of a finger
4. Can i connect to a remote server on a website and pull/push data through usual POST/GET methods?
5. Can i mix the normal XML based android display with the 3D display, or should i open it in a different screen(aka full screen).

Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere, need to know the above things before i take up this project for sure. Helpful links would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend LibGDX for the graphics. Very easy to use, lets you prototype on your PC, and lets you call OpenGL functions as well. 

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Comment: @MikeLentini Thanks. I will try that one. Its the best 3D out there in open-source?

Comment: Not sure if it is the best, but it is definitely fast, easy to use, and open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK already comes with OpenGL which is a free and open source 3D rendering API.

1. Yes, of course.
2. Yes. You'll have to model it yourself of course.
3. Yes, AFAIK that's what 3D is all about...
4. Yes, of course, why it would be otherwise?
5. Yes. You can divide the display with the usual XML layout, but 3D must be drawn over a special surface (GLSurfaceView).

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, And about the 3D rendering API can i have a few links, @Mike Lentini sugested LibGDX, What do you suggest?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have such experience. I just started recently with Android 3D with OpenGL. I gave a link about it.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend checking out the Google IO video on Android 3D rendering http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLVbLVtjDDw

Comment: cool, this is very helpful, sadly i could accept only 1 answer :P

Comment: No worries, your upvote took me to 1K :)